# Highchart: To display percent on each and every column of Column chart

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, highcharts

How to set different colors to different datalabels of all columns in this bar chart. In this code , I just set with orange color for all data labels in this chart.
How can apply different colors to all datalabels on top of columns.

```
  column: {

               colorByPoint: true,
                borderWidth: 0,


               dataLabels: {
                         format: '{point.y:.f}%',
                         enabled: true,
                    style: {
                            fontWeight: 'normal',
                        fontSize: '30px',
                color: '#FF6F61',
                fontFamily:'Sans Serif Regular',
                textOutline: '1px contrast'
                            }
                         },

              series: {
                     pointWidth: 195,   
                         minPointLength: 50,
                        colors :[
                     '#800000', 
                     '#DB7093', 
                     '#FF7F50', 
                     '#008080', 
                     '#006400'

                     ]

                    }
           }
        };  
        var credits = {
           enabled: false
        };
        var series= [
           {

              name: 'HSBC',
              data: [{y:50}, {y:10},{y:30}, {y:9}, {y:1}]

           }

        ];
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you want.  Do you want the dataLables above the columns or inside the columns, but at the top?

Comment: Hello Barbara..I want to display dataLabels above the columns only. It should display the value with percent symbol. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you'd like the labels above the columns formatted with a %.
You're not actually using stacking columns, but that is where the orange labels are coming from (stackLabels).  So, remove those and then use the default placement for the column labels.

```
column: {

  dataLabels: {
    format: '{point.y:.1f}%',
    enabled: true,
    color: 'Black'
  },

  colorByPoint: true,
  borderWidth: 0
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zkb70gsa/